# Running regressions with different columns of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, lm

I am trying to replicate the results of Romer & Romer (2004) with the Jordá website script. I have the following dataframe in ts format

[image]

I try to make the dependent variable for each h take ur1, ur2, ..., urh. The code I have written is the following but I don't get any result:

```
#Local projections by OLS
library(dynlm)
library(sandwich)

bh <- matrix(nrow = hmax, ncol = 3)

for (h in 7:(6+hmax)) {
  
      reg <- dynlm(df_ts[,h] ~ DFF + L(DFF,1) + L(DFF,2) + L(DFF,3) + L(DFF,4) 
                    + L(UNRATE,1) + L(UNRATE,2) + L(UNRATE,3) + L(UNRATE,4), data = df_ts)  
        
        #Store coefficient of DFF
        bh[h,1] = reg$coefficients[[2]]
        
        #HAC VAR-COV Matrix
        NW_VCOV <- NeweyWest(reg, lag = h, prewhite = F, adjust = T)
        
        # compute standard error
        sd <- sqrt(diag(NW_VCOV))[[2]]
        se <- sd/(length(UNRATE)-h)
        
        #Store Upper and Lower bands
        bh[h,2] <- bh[h,1] + 1.96 * se
        bh[h,3] <- bh[h,1] - 1.96 * se
}
```

I am trying to replicate the stata script "lpiv_example.do" from https://sites.google.com/site/oscarjorda/home/local-projections.